# Images failed to load

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to dynamically changing image src using jquery with image path from the database.

This code here is inside a form tag

```
<img src="images/Desert.jpg" alt="..." style="height:100px;width:200px;" class="img-thumbnail">

var j = 0;
$.each(lectObject, function(){

if (j == 1) {
     $('form#unitOne img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}else if (j == 2) {
     $('form#unitTwo img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}else if (j == 3) {
     $('form#unitThree img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}else if (j == 4) {
    $('form#unitFour img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}else if (j == 5) {
    $('form#unitFive img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}else if (j == 6) {
    $('form#unitSix img').attr({src: lectObject[2]});
}

j++
});
```

My concern is that, the src is succesfully change, ecause when i inspect element i see the path i want, but unfortunately the image faile to load!

Comment: what errors do you get in the console?

Comment: This error here: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/raters.com/public/images%5CNGzUuF_8.jpg"

Comment: so im guessing that `lectObject[2]` is == `CNGzUuF_8.jpg`? what is right url for that image? looks like is just a spacing, or back slashing that is messing it up

Comment: awesome, that is very true! Instead of http://localhost/raters.com/public/images%5CNGzUuF_8.jpg",   must be http://localhost/raters.com/public/images/5CNGzUuF_8.jpg"

Comment: okay so try `console.log(lectObject[2]);` what do you see?

Comment: also to make sure there is not white space in the data, use `$.trim(obj)`

Comment: when is console.log i get \images\myoNOr_1.jpg   ,  but the error says http://localhost/raters.com/public/%5Cimages%5CILOSiJ_3.jpg"         , i do not understand where these %5C comes from . . .

Comment: Try running Your  lectObject[2] though an encodeURIComponent() first.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: or you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417641/converting-backslashes-into-forward-slashes-using-javascript-does-not-work-prope to change the back slash to forward slash ;)

Comment: @jycr753 %5C is a backslash...

Comment: yeah i know @MarkJones it didnt know could not do back slash symbol

Comment: Ah,  ;) Forgot about formatting here.

Comment: @jycr753, i just check, there is no ` in the database where i keep the path

Comment: @MarkJones, i just change backslash to forwardslash, the error changed to "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/raters.com/public/images%2FTRL6or_7.jpg"  so instead of %5C i am getting %2F

Comment: can you post array from the database so I can debug it ;)

Comment: This is what i get from database images/brMljr_14.jpg, i console.log it and saw! But when i changed img attribute to it the / changes to %2C

Comment: do you have magic quotes on?

Comment: where can i check that ?

Comment: phpinfo.. that function if on it will escape all slashes

Comment: Is there anyway to escape the slashes using jquery

Comment: I did put a link before you should check out.

Comment: @jycr753, thank you very much for your help, the images just loaded correctly! I removed the encodeURIComponent() added initially