# escape & unescape backslashes using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backslash

Here are the test cases

- \\192.168.100.1\foldername\filename
- actividirectoryName\username
- somethingelse\text\\and this
- \

How do I escape these strings and again un-escape it.

I tried something like this `"mystring\something".replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\');`
but it do sent work right when I have string like `"name\b" or "text\n" or "text\t"`

Since those are reserved keys to tab, newline and other.
What is the best way to handle this

**Update:**
even here in this edit i had to write 3 back slashes to show you two back slashes? when I first wrote 2 back slashes, it was showing only 1 back slash

Comment: Why do you need to escape them? If you're putting them in a URL, try `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: not in URL. this is the text added in textarea field in a web form. And how do i decode it back. "string\b" id not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417641/converting-backslashes-into-forward-slashes-using-javascript-does-not-work-prope

Comment: @HarpreetSingh i don't want to convert those to something. I want to escape those and use it. and again un-escape those

Comment: I think you need to create a proper test case. Write [a snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Use a textarea in your demo since you are using a textarea in the real code. Explain why you need to escape the data (at the moment you only say you are unescaping it, so there must be an important middle step we are missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to solve this depends on where these strings are stored.

There are only two ways of handling this, both of which require storing the variables else where before using them.

If you are using php you can use Raw. If you are doing ajax requests or loading values into the DOM, you can use javascript to get those values, and they will be held with the baskslashes.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('id');
var a = document.getElementById('v').value;
var b = String.raw `${a}`
var c = String.raw `\\192.168.100.1\foldername\filename`
var d = '\\192.168.100.1\foldername\filename'
var test = [
  d + ' - in JavaScript',
  c + ' - in raw',
  a + ' - in HTML',
  b + ' - in raw variable'
];
for (var i = 0, l = test.length; i < l; i++) {
  text.value += test[i] + '\n';
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id='v' value='\\192.168.100.1\foldername\filename' type='hidden' />
<textarea rows='10' id='id'></textarea>
```

To use php and raw it would look something like this

```
String.raw`<?=$variable?>`
```

**EDIT** Once you have this raw data you can start using REGEX and other escaping means on it.

```js
var c = String.raw `\\192.168.100.1\foldername\filename<\/p>`
var text2 = document.getElementById('id2');
text2.value = (c + '').replace('\\\\', '\\').replace('\\/', '/');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows='10' id='id2'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i got a extended question on this. How do I replace <\/span><\/p> like </span></p> and domain\\user\'s like domain\user\'s

Comment: replace('\\\\', '\\').replace('\\/', '/'); this will only replace the first occurrence, not all occurrences

Comment: finally got it worked with little more changes to what you gave